# Apache setup: directive requires additional arguments

Tags: apache

I am trying to use an Apache (only localhost) on macOS. When I do `apachectl configtest` I get the following response:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 238 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:
<Directory> directive requires additional arguments
```

The corresponding part of the httpd.conf file is

```
DocumentRoot ~/Sites
<Directory />
 Options Indexes SymLinks
 MultiviewsMatch Any
 AllowOverride None
 Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I consulted several forums / the Apache documentation but I cannot see the mistake. Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By writing `<Directory />`, you are telling Apache that the Directory tag closes right away.  So the configuration you put is equivalent to

```
<Directory>
</Directory>

 Options Indexes SymLinks
 MultiviewsMatch Any
 AllowOverride None
 Require all granted
</Directory>
```

since "/>" terminates the "<Directory" tag.

Modify it this way:

```
<Directory "/">
 Options Indexes SymLinks
 MultiviewsMatch Any
 AllowOverride None
 Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Note that "/"  will be the "/" of your machine.  So you are granting access to "/" on your system via Apache...